# Git-Error when pulling from origin: "you must provide a non-zero number of processes!"

Tags: git, git-extensions

Today I updated to the latest git version (2.39.0).

When I'm pulling from origin with GitExtensions (4.0.0.15569) I now receive an error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" pull --progress --jobs=0 "origin"
BUG: run-command.c:1521: you must provide a non-zero number of processes!
```

Has anyone seen this error before? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I guess `--jobs=0` does not make sense.

Comment: I just tested and it worked with `2.37.2`.  Can you check what it says in `git help pull` about `--jobs`?

Comment: From the docs:
Number of parallel children to be used for all forms of fetching.

If the --multiple option was specified, the different remotes will be fetched in parallel. If multiple submodules are fetched, they will be fetched in parallel. To control them independently, use the config settings fetch.parallel and submodule.fetchJobs (see git-config(1)).

Typically, parallel recursive and multi-remote fetches will be faster. By default fetches are performed sequentially, not in parallel.

Comment: I do not see anything there that would mean that `0` is not valid anymore.

Comment: I will try downgrading git. Maybe there is an incompatibility between the two programs now.

Comment: Its the same error for fetching from origin by the way.

Comment: What happens if you try with a non-0 value?

Comment: If I'd knew where to put that I would do that. There is no setting in the GIT Extension settings dialog.

Comment: It's still working with 2.38.1. So I assume it's a bug (or intended breaking change) in the new GIT release.

Comment: Here is [the related issue](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/10514) - appearantly, the change in git was intentional. There's already [a fix](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/10521) there for git extensions, but it has not been released yet.

Comment: Update: I can confirm that the 4.0.1 release of git extensions fixes the issues (released today).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrading to [Git Extensions 4.0.1.15887](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/releases/tag/v4.0.1) fixes the issue.

It seems like they updated the pull button to use the following flags:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c fetch.parallel=0 -c submodule.fetchJobs=0 pull --progress "origin
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as several have noted, is due to the `--jobs=0` option.  Supply a nonzero value (such as 1) here.  However, this *is* a Git bug: if `0` is invalid, it should print a *different error message*.  If zero means "use a default" (as it did in earlier Git versions), Git should have picked a default.

Any time you see Git print:

```
BUG: <rest of stuff>
```

you can rest assured that you have simply found a bug in Git.  It's not something *you* did wrong, Git is broken.  It may be a trivial bug (as this one is) but it was self-detected *as* a bug.  So you may be able to work around it, but it's still a bug in Git.

Comment: That was an intentional change in git: https://github.com/git/git/commit/51243f9f0f6a932ea579fd6f8014b348f8c2a523

Comment: @RussKie: indeed, and we can see from the commit message that Ævar *thought* they'd gotten all the user-level command line "jobs=0" cases. But they hadn't! If the intent is to make `--jobs=0` invalid as a command line option, Git should be printing a message along the lines of "fatal: --jobs value must be at least 1". If it prints "BUG:" it means someone missed something.